# windows 8 - how does one avoid signing into email account

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook, skype

Can one avoid signing into the email account that Windows 8 constantly requests. To open any applications (games, skype or download from the app store) there is that prompt to input Microsoft email account. I do not want Microsoft to "save this info so you can use this account with skype or Solitaire" or whatever app I want to get into. How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your account to a local account. Bring up the right-hand-side bar (using upper right hotspot) and choose `settings`. Down the bottom is a small text `Change PC Settings` option. In the `Users` page, underneath your username will be a `Switch to a local Account` button. This will convert your account to a local one, which will disable all or most of the calling home requirements.

Comment: Can you still download from the app store after doing this step?

Answer (score 0):

Create a local account

Control Panel
users
when you create a new account make sure it is local

Comment: Need a better description